# Converting values using JAXB

Tags: jaxb

I have a String value that I wish to set into a bean using JAXB. So I have an instance of RuntimeTypeInfoSet and I can get the RuntimePropertyInfo and from that call getAccessor to get an Accessor for the property. The problem is that the Accessor requires the value to already be of the right type. How do I convert it?

Comment: `RuntimeTypeInfoSet` is specific to the JAXB (JSR-222) reference implementation.  Are you trying to use a JAXB implementation to populate an object outside of an unmarshal operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a Transducer instance:

```
switch (property.kind()) {
    case VALUE:
    case ATTRIBUTE:
        transducer = ((RuntimeNonElementRef) property).getTransducer();
        break;
    case ELEMENT:
        transducer = ((RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) property).getTypes().get(0).getTransducer();
        break;
    case REFERENCE:
    case MAP:
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Don't know how to handle property kind " + property.kind() + " for " + property);
}
```